# Clojure Higher-order functions take function arguments, but what is the syntax?

Tags: clojure

I am doing the closure tutorial at http://clojurescriptkoans.com and I am stuck here: http://clojurescriptkoans.com/#functions/9

It looks like this

Higher-order functions take function arguments

```
(= 25 ( _ (fn [n] (* n n))))
```

I am supposed to fill in something at the underscore to make the expression true.   I have no clue what to do.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The syntax simply consists of binding the function, and then calling it.

Since this is an exercise, I will show a similar situation rather than showing the exercise's solution:

```
user> ((fn [f] (f "abc")) (fn [s] (str s s s)))
"abcabcabc"
```

here I bind the argument of the first function to `f`, and call `f` with the argument `"abc"`.

Comment: So the specific answer for the expression in question is  (= 25 ( (fn [f] (f 5)) (fn [n] (* n n)))), is that correct?

Comment: I think so, that evaluates to `true` in my repl.

Answer (score 5):

or you can use the short-hand notation:

```
#(%1 5)
```

Comment: Even shorter: `#(% 5)`

Answer (score 0):

Higher order functions takes functions as arguments.
Defining two functions

```
user=> (defn multiply [n] (* n n))
#'user/multiply

user=> (defn add [n] (+ n n))
#'user/add
```

Defining higher order function

```
user=> (defn highorderfn [fn number] (fn number))
#'user/highorderfn
```

Calling the higher order function

```
user=> (highorderfn multiply 5)
25
user=> (highorderfn add 5)
10
```

Comment: This is considered here at StackOverflow a "code-only" answer and not appreciated. Would you like to improve it by adding some explanation how and why this helps? Try to also highlight how this givess additional insight to existing older, better explained, upvoted and accepted answers. Please take the [tour] and consider the recommendations in [answer].